# How to use javascript timers with mvc5?

Tags: javascript, timer, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an `DropDownList` which holds list of patients and a table which holds the vital signs of selected patient in the same view(page). I used JavaScript to set timer so that the DropDownList and table both could refresh every 5 seconds. but it only refresh the DropDownList. When I click a patient name in the dropdown I got an error like this

> "EmployeeListItems = 'model.EmployeeListItems' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException'" and object reference not set to an instance of an object

This is my view

```
@model eVitalz_mvc.Models.PatientlistModel
....
 <script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function ()
    {
        $.post("@Url.Action("ListPatients", "Home")", {}, function () { 
        });
    }, 5000)
 </script>

<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Patient list:
        </td>
        <td>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("ListPatients", "Home",FormMethod.Post, new { id = "demoForm", name = "demoForm" }))
            {
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Preg_id, Model.EmployeeListItems, "---Select---", new { Class = "ddlStyle", onchange = "SelectedIndexChanged()" })
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<h1 style="color: #2D3F43; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; text-align: center">Glucose</h1>
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Image_Glucose" src="~/images-old-evitalz/blood1.png" style="height: 100px; width: auto" />
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl_glucose_unit">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Glucose) mmol</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my model class

```
public class PatientlistModel
{
    public static string s = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConn"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(s);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    public List<PatientlistModel> Patients { get; set; }
    public int Preg_id { get; set; }
    public string P_Name { get; set; }
    public string  age { get; set; }
    public string temperature { get; set; }
    public string Glucose { get; set; }
    public string Pressure_SYS { get; set; }
    public string Pressure_DIA { get; set; }
    public string Pressure_PR { get; set; }
    public string Oximeter_SPO2 { get; set; }
    public string Oximeter_PR { get; set; }
    public string ECG { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EmployeeListItems
    {
        get
        {
            return new SelectList(Patients, "Preg_id", "P_Name");
        }
    }
}
```

This is my controller action

```
public ActionResult ListPatients()
{
    PatientlistModel pt = new PatientlistModel();
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["uid"]);
    pt.Patients = PopulatePatientList(id);
    return View(pt);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ListPatients(PatientlistModel model)
{
    int s = Convert.ToInt32(model.Preg_id);
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["pid"] = s;
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["uid"]);
    PatientlistModel obj = new PatientlistModel();
    obj.Patients = PopulatePatientList(Convert.ToInt32(id));
    //sample code to get glucose
    obj.Glucose = emp1.Rows[m]["D_Value1"].ToString();
    return View(obj);
}
```

Comment: Your javascript code does not refresh anything! Its an ajax call and your not even doing anything with the data that you return from the method in the success callback. And since you never pass data to the POST method, then `int s = Convert.ToInt32(model.Preg_id);`means the value of `s` would be `0` no doubt causing all the other code to fail.

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke can you please guide me how to fix this problem .

Comment: Its not clear what you want to do. Why do you want to update the dropdownlist? And why every 5 seconds? (the user would not know that some new `Patients` have been added - only the selected option is visible). Do you actually only want to update the table?

Comment: And what are you doing in your `SelectedIndexChanged()` function?

Comment: `$.post` is a shorthand of `$.ajax({ type: 'POST', ... })` and not to be confused with actual form submit (`$('form').submit()`). Since the form submitted without using `PatientlistModel`, then that viewmodel is not populated and throwing `ArgumentNullException` when trying to populate DDLF.

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke . I am submitting the form using the following js              <script type="text/javascript">

    function SelectedIndexChanged() {
      
        document.demoForm.submit();
    }
</script>